# no terminal output in VS CODE

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5dHC.png)

whenever I run the code in VS-Code instead of retunring the string it says "File hello world not found"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is because you're trying to run python code in the terminal, try running test.py instead.

Comment: Please also do not post terminal/code output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you run the python command in the terminal which does not understand python. So can use "python namefile.py" or simply "python" and then write you line code.

Comment: Works, thank you! But how do I change it so it automatically knows it's python code? This only happens on my laptop .. When I run code on my desktop it automatically returns the output in the terminal.

Comment: That's probably because you open a Python interpreter instead of Bash terminal.